# I am trying to make a replica UI of a calculator app using Flutter and I am stuck in a few things

Tags: android, flutter, user-interface, dart, flutter-layout

I have been able to make a major part of the UI but few elements are still creating a problem for me.

This is the screenshot of the original UI of the app.

[Original Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t0TFP.jpg)

And this is the screenshot of the UI that I have been able to make up till now using Flutter

[Screenshot of UI made with the help of flutter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kyiUQ.jpg)

Now can you please help me regarding how can I make that '=' container go to the extreme right just like in the original screenshot. And as well how should I align the first row on the same level as in the original UI.

This is the code that I have made for the container having all the digits.

```
Expanded(
            child: Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Color(0xFF212121),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(topRight: Radius.circular(10.0), topLeft: Radius.circular(10.0)),
              ),
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  Icon(Icons.remove, color: Colors.grey, size: 40.0,),
                  Buttons(
                    widget1: Text('AC', style: kNumber2TextStyle,),
                    widget2: Icon(Icons.backspace_outlined, size: 25.0, color: Colors.white,),
                    widget3: Text('%', style: kNumberTextStyle,),
                    widget4: Text('÷', style: kButton2TextStyle,),
                  ),
                  Buttons(
                    widget1: Text('7', style: kNumberTextStyle,),
                    widget2: Text('8', style: kNumberTextStyle,),
                    widget3: Text('9', style: kNumberTextStyle,),
                    widget4: Text('x', style: kButtonTextStyle,),
                  ),
                  Buttons(
                    widget1: Text('4', style: kNumberTextStyle,),
                    widget2: Text('5', style: kNumberTextStyle,),
                    widget3: Text('6', style: kNumberTextStyle,),
                    widget4: Text('-', style: kButton2TextStyle,),
                  ),
                  Buttons(
                    widget1: Text('1', style: kNumberTextStyle,),
                    widget2: Text('2', style: kNumberTextStyle,),
                    widget3: Text('3', style: kNumberTextStyle,),
                    widget4: Text('+', style: kButtonTextStyle,),
                  ),
                  Buttons(
                    widget1: Text('.', style: kNumberTextStyle,),
                    widget2: Text('0', style: kNumberTextStyle,),
                    widget3: Text('( )', style: kNumberTextStyle,),
                    widget4: Container(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(30.0),
                      color: Color(0xFFFFBE00),
                      child: Text('=', style: kNumberTextStyle,),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          )
```

Please help!

Answer (score 1):

there are several ways to achieve this, as learning curve, I recommend you read how [flexible](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Flexible-class.html) / [expanded](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Expanded-class.html) works

Colum and inside it, rows, each row will contain the buttons, use flexible or expanded in order to occupy the entire row not matter the display.